# JOINs across MySQL and MongoDB/HBase for analytics data

Tags: mysql, mongodb, join, analytics, hbase

We are looking to build an internal real-time analytics system using MongoDB or HBase (other options possible, but these are the two we are looking at right now.) We picked these two because:

- We will be recording a huge number of events, and want to be able to
  horizontally and vertically scale.
- We will get "long tail" requests - for example, "give me the metrics for this item three years ago" - and hence need to do real-time queries over a large range, whether time or other values.

We have tried to use MySQL for the analytics tables, but the tables get large really fast and we don't want our analytics tables to be a "dead weight" on the rest of our MySQL system. (I am open to advice on using MySQL or other solutions for analytics tables if anyone has insight.)

So, the question is: we will often have to do real-time lookups and JOINs across both our analytics data store and MongoDB/Hbase. For instance, we will be storing the "id" of a table in analytics, but for any request, we will have to "join" it against, say, the "title" and "content" fields of a "content" table in MySQL.

Is there any way to do JOINs across MongoDB/HBase and MySQL, or is this something we would have to custom-build into our application? And if we build it in the application, how would we deal with custom JOINs on large data sets across MySQL and MongoDB/HBase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to do JOINs across MongoDB/HBase and MySQL...

MongoDB has absolutely zero support for JOINs. You would basically have to build your own join system if you use MongoDB

HBase is build over top of Hadoop and, in theory, [some JOIN-like syntax is possible](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1257).

However, joining between MySQL and HBase is almost certainly custom code. You may want to consider copying the MySQL data *into* HBase.

> ... need to do real-time queries over a large range... *"give me the metrics for this item three years ago"*

Recognize that this is going to be a tremendous challenge and that you are unlikely to find anything "out of the box" that does this for you.

You will need to be very judicious about the term "real-time". It sounds like you want "relatively responsive queries" rather than "real-time queries". You will have to scope "relatively responsive" as this will massively affect both the cost and the products you use.

Comment: Sorry, when I said "JOIN", I was pretty much sure I would have to do "application-level JOINs", but was wondering whether others had done this before. I realize that this must have to be a custom build.

Comment: Regarding "relatively responsive queries" vs "real-time queries": would this depend on the choice of MongoDB/HBase/other? Or on the choice of key? Or other factors?

Comment: Other way around, you have to pick what type of queries you want and then use the appropriate tool. *"Real-time"* generally refers to *"what has happened in the last 15 minutes"*. But you're talking about fetching data from 3 years ago with some user-defined fields. That's an ad-hoc query and has nothing to do with "real-time", you just want that query to respond in a reasonable time.

Comment: Of course *"reasonable"* is really key. If you had infinite RAM and infinite disk space you could probably make *everything* really fast. But you will probably have a limited amount of both so you have to figure out what is "acceptably slow" before you pick any system.